# No Sound in gTTS

Tags: machine-learning, gtts

I am trying to convert text to speech using gTTS.

```
import subprocess
from gtts import gTTS

mytext = 'Hello Rasa Bot User, I am a Bot'
language ='en'
myobj = gTTS(text = mytext, lang=language)
myobj.save("welcome.mp3")
subprocess.call(['mpg321',"welcome.mp3",'--play-and-exit'])
```

But it seems that I don't get to hear any sound. I am doing this in Ubuntu and using PyCharm.
The contents of the terminal are as follows:

```
(venv) rome@rome-VirtualBox:~/Desktop/rasa/intr2$ python ttos.py
mpg321: unrecognized option '--play-and-exit'
High Performance MPEG 1.0/2.0/2.5 Audio Player for Layer 1, 2, and 3.
Version 0.3.2-1 (2012/03/25). Written and copyrights by Joe Drew,
now maintained by Nanakos Chrysostomos and others.
Uses code from various people. See 'README' for more!
THIS SOFTWARE COMES WITH ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY! USE AT YOUR OWN RISK!

Playing MPEG stream from welcome.mp3 ...
MPEG 2.0 layer III, 32 kbit/s, 24000 Hz mono
```

Please Help !!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the pygame library to play the audio.

Here is the code which will play audio using gtts library:

```
from gtts import gTTS
from pygame import mixer #to play the audio
text="Hello Rasa Bot User! I am a Bot"
tts = gTTS(text=text, lang="en")
tts.save("temp.mp3") # save the audio in a temp file 
mixer.music.load('temp.mp3')# load the audio file
mixer.music.play()
```

Answer (score 0):

Hello I think I can help you

```
From gtts import gTTS
Import playsound 

Text= "hello world"
tts =gTTS(text=text , lang="en")
tts.save("hello.mp3")
playsound=playsound("hello.mp3")
```

Comment: Please add a bit more detail about why and how this works.